# Can I make emacs correctly load source files when using gdb over ssh?

Tags: emacs, ssh, gdb, remote-debugging

I want to use emacs to remotely run gdb over ssh, then from that remote gdb, target a remote debug server.  I really want to run gdb from within emacs, but x-forwarding emacs has too much latency so I run aquamacs locally on my mac.  I run M-x gdb with the command line `ssh work-host /path/to/my/gdb` and then from the gdb prompt I can target my remote debug target.

This all works great, but no sources load when I try and step through files.  I'm assuming emacs is getting confused at the remote paths the ssh gdb is returning.  Is there a way to fix up the paths or at least manually map file paths to debug paths?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (Emacs 23 under Linux and GDB 7.0.1; I don't see why this wouldn't work on OSX, and probably even on Windows with a bit of prodding):

```
M-x gdb --annotate=3 /remote.example.com:a.out
```

Then `start` at the `(gdb)` prompt opened `/remote.example.com:a.c`.

There is some brief mention of this in the [Tramp manual, under “Running a debugger on a remote host”](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Remote-processes).

Comment: The real complication is that I'm debugging an embedded device, and I don't want to have to compile a compatible gdb for this device on my mac, hence the double remote-ing.  I believe this wouldn't work because my x86 mac's native gdb won't be able to debug my powerpc-linux-uclibc compiled software.

Comment: @jdizzle My bad, I'd completely missed the double remoting. Both gdb and emacs are pretty versatile, so there's probably a way to make this work. Could you post a transcript of how you start gdb? Where are the source files stored? Can gdb open them (e.g. does the `list` command work)?

Answer (score 1):

> x-forwarding emacs has too much latency

So don't. The simplest solution may be to ssh to work-host, and run `emacs -nw` there. Alternatively,

> ssh work-host /path/to/my/gdb

Don't you want `ssh work-host /path/to/my/gdb --annotate=3 /path/to/exe` ?

You can tell `gdb` where to find sources with the `dir` command, but I think your initial problem might be that `gdb` isn't telling `emacs` about source at all (or else you have not told us the whole story).